Help in solving indefinite integral involving trigonometric functions
Although I found plenty integrals which look similar, e.g. I am struggling with the following indefinite integral:
\begin{equation}
I = \int\frac{1}{(x+cos(x))^{2} + sin^{2}(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}
Also, checking with WolframAlpha or a handbook of integrals like Gradshteyn did not result in a solution. Do you have any hint for me on how to approach this problem (e.g., shall I look for a particular class of solutions like elliptic integrals)? Thank you very much.

The term $x+\cos x$ together with $\sin x$ prevents any standard substitution for the indefinite integral. The standard substitution for rationals of trigonometric fumctions $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$  removes the trigs but introduces an $\tan^{-1}$ term for $x$.

This is too long for a comment.
As @RolandF commented, there is no hope to compute
$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2 x \cos (x)+1} $$ But, suppose that you need to provide a formal approximation of it; you could use my favored $1,400^+$ years old approximation of the cosine function
$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad \text{for} \qquad -\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2$$ and obtain
$$I \sim \int \frac {x^2+\pi^2 } {x^4-8 x^3+\left(1+\pi ^2\right) x^2+2\pi ^2 x+\pi^2 }\,dx$$ The quartic equation can be solved with radicals (it has two real roots) and we can write
$$A=\frac {x^2+\pi^2 } {x^4-8 x^3+\left(1+\pi ^2\right) x^2+2\pi ^2 x+\pi^2 }=\frac{x^2+\pi ^2}{(x-a) (x-b) \left(x^2+cx+d\right)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$A=\frac{\alpha}{x-a}+\frac{\beta}{ x-b}+\frac {\gamma\, x+\delta} {x^2+c x+d}$$  would give
$$I \sim \alpha  \log (x-a)+\beta  \log (x-b)+\frac{1}{2} \gamma  \,\log \left(x^2+cx+d\right)+$$ $$\frac{2 \delta -c\, \gamma }{\sqrt{4
   d-c^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 x+c}{\sqrt{4 d-c^2}}\right)$$
Just to give an idea of the accuracy, computing the last integral from $-\frac \pi 2$ to $\frac \pi 2$ would give $2.95192$ while numerically, the true integral gives $2.95609$ (relative error of $0.14$%).
To give an idea about the accuracy, look at the infinite norm
$$\Phi=\int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \Bigg( \frac{1}{x^2+2 x \cos (x)+1}-A\Bigg)^2\,dx=3.804\times 10^{-5}$$
If you need to work in other regions, just shift $x$ accordingly to stay in the appropriate domain.

thank you very much! Again, you could help me with my problem!

At this point everybody (every physicist having heard about multipole expansions) continues with the expansion into Chebyshev Polynomials of the 2nd Kind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x^2+2x\cos x+1}
=
\sum_{n\ge 0}\int U_n(-\cos x)x^n dx
$$
assuming that $|x|<1$.

this looks also like a very interesting approach. Thank you very much for this advice!

This is good idea for sure. I

You can write
$$\frac{1}{x^2+2 x \cos (x)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \, \frac {(2x)^n }{(1+x^2)^{n+1} }\,\cos^n(x)$$
$$I_n=\int  \frac {(2x)^n }{(1+x^2)^{n+1} }\,\cos^n(x)\,dx$$ can be computed but the process is quite long : it requires the linearization of $\cos^n(x)$, partial fraction decomposition.
For example, for $I_1$
$$ \frac {2x }{(1+x^2)^{2} }=\frac i 2\left(\frac{1}{(x+i)^2}-\frac{1}{(x-i)^2} \right)$$
$$\int  \frac{\cos (x)}{(x+a)^2}\,dx=\int \frac{\cos (t-a)}{t^2}\,dt=$$ $$\cos(a)\int \frac{\cos (t)}{t^2}\,dt+\sin(a)\int \frac{\sin (t)}{t^2}\,dt=$$
$$\sin (a)\, \text{Ci}(t)-\cos (a)\, \text{Si}(t)-\frac{\cos (t-a)}{t}$$ Back to $x$, an already long and tedious formula.
To give an idea, have a look here for $I_4$

interesting! where does $\frac{1}{x^2+2 x \cos (x)+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n , \frac {(2x)^n }{(1+x^2)^{n+1} },\cos^n(x)$ come from?
this also shows again, why my integral is so difficult to solve
